# android browser scrolling issue in phonegp application

Tags: android, html, cordova, scroll

In my phonegap application scrolling working fine in some of the devices (android ), but in some of the devices **scrolling content does not work.**

Simple structure of my page as below :

## ------------Header-----------

## ------------content-----------

## ------------footer-------------

Sample Code :

```
<div id="header"> </div>

<div id="content"> 
This content does not scroll when overflow
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>


Header and footer is fixed size and position ( top and bottom).
```

When i try to scroll content area it will not work in some of the android devices.

Thanks in advance for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iScroll or NiceScroll js plugin for smooth scrolling of the content.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: can i do it without library. because if i use library i need to change my whole structure that is too difficult right now.

Comment: You can use CSS3 code -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; but it will not work with the lower version of Android like 2.3.

Comment: does it support in >2.3 ?

Comment: Yes It will. For additional info you can follow this link http://engineering.bergcloud.com/2013/06/android-chrome-and-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch/

Comment: i am using phonegap it run on crome by default?

Comment: If you mean to say Android uses Webkit engine, its yes.

Comment: i am run my app like : super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000); does it support -webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: You are creating the app for Android using PhoneGap. And PhoneGap supports the -webkit-overflow-scrolling css property.

Comment: Thanks @Sourav, i know phonegap support this,but my problem in some of the android device only so it wil work for all android devices???.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36251/discussion-between-sourav-and-butani-vijay)

Answer (score 2):

hi You can use **overflow scroll**  option in css but Android 3.0 and higher have support for overflow:scroll,   **< 3.0 it's not support**.  for that you can use iscroll http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 or any other  plugin.

Comment: i am trying in 4.0 but it does not support

Comment: @ButaniVijay overflow supports in 4.0 sure  , if not giv ur code

Comment: problem in some of the device only.

Comment: i think some of the ICS have issue ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you are making the application using html then you have to set a touchable scroller. Their is various plugin available in the market. So you can use any of them.

But there is some scroller which is not supported by android. You have to choose correct one for it. I am giving you a link where you can find a scroller. I have used it. It will work like a charm.

http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: OP will be notified when u have posted an answer... no need to post comment under question everytime u answers...

Answer (score 0):

you can try using style properties for `<div>`

**overflow** and **overflow-y**
,for me its working fine.

```
<div style='height: 190px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: scroll !important;'>
```